# Add to UIScrollView.contentInset.top

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uiedgeinsets

In my attempt to [Keep UISearchBar visible even if user is sliding down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340345/keep-uisearchbar-visible-even-if-user-is-sliding-down), I've:

- Added a `UITableView` & `UISearchView` as subviews of `view`.

  - `tableView`'s `frame` = `view.bounds`
  - `searchBar` is locked to the bottom of `topLayoutGuide` with Auto Layout.

But, since even with `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true`, the `searchBar` covers the `tableView`, how do I increase `tableView.contentInset.top` by 44 (the `searchBar`'s height)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
UIEdgeInsets insets = tableView.contentInset;
insets.top += 44;
tableView.contentInset = insets;
```

Comment: Yeah, but, I'm using Swift, so it's just one line: `tableView.contentInset.top += 44`. But, I couldn't figure out where to do it. So, I just repositioned the `tableView` snapping its top to the `searchBar`'s bottom. That way, the `tableView` is no longer behind the `searchBar`. I'm happy with it. :-)

Comment: Maybe it's because I don't know much swift, but wouldn't the exact same lines work? Maybe with an extra `var` or `let` on the initial variable creation line?

Comment: Yep, I just don't know where/when to adjust the insets.

Comment: You could do this in your view controller's `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: It doesn't work in `viewDidLoad` because `topLayoutGuide.length` is still `0` then. It might work in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, but that gets called a lot, so you'd probably need additional logic and/or memory. I tried subclassing `UITableView` and overriding `contentInset` and adding 44 to `conentInset.top` and subtracting 44 from `contentOffset.y` in `didSet`. That worked for the first call to `contentInset` but then broke after subsequent calls. So, I think if I added a boolean property and some logic to only make that adjustment once, that would work. But, I'd rather stick with what I have.

Comment: Why does `topLayoutGuide.length` have any effect on your ability to set `.contentInset`? Also, if this is layout that changes based on some condition, it absolutely belongs in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. If you find `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is being called "a lot", try investigating the reason that it's called so often. Even if it is called often, setting `.contentInset` within it is not going to have any significant impact on performance, and it won't cause any visual glitches.

Comment: Since `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true `, if `topLayoutGuide.length` is `0`, then `tableView.contentInset.top` will also be `0`, then `44` after I add to it, and then `64` after being automatically adjusted. But, I want it to be `64 + 44`. Yeah, adjusting `tableView.contentInset.top` in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` makes sense since `tableView.contentInset.top` is dependent on `topLayoutGuide.length`. Still, I think I'll pass for now because I already implemented the solution in my first comment. But, thanks! :-)